# Error 13043 when trying to submit product feed to Amazon MWS

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I am using MWS to send a product feed to Amazon.

This is what I am sending (in the product feed, not the price feed)
using type of: _POST_PRODUCT_DATA_

Why am I getting an error saying my price is not good?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
   <Header>
   <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
   <MerchantIdentifier></MerchantIdentifier>
   </Header>
   <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
           <Message>
                   <MessageID>1</MessageID>
                   <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
                   <Product>
                           <SKU>WAL-0011</SKU>

                           <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_TAX</ProductTaxCode>
                           <Condition>
                                   <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
                           </Condition>
                           <DescriptionData>
                                   <Title><![CDATA[ FLAMES FIRE TRIFOLD 4" LEATHER NEW Biker WALLET & CHAIN ]]></Title>
                                   <Description><![CDATA[ The awesome, Black, soft leather, tri-fold four inch wallet. This wallet includes a detachable chain with snapping belt loop as well as a "Flame" screen print. This great functional and stylish wallet makes a great gift! <BR ]]></Description>



                           </DescriptionData>
                           <ProductData>

                                   <Miscellaneous>
                                           <ProductType>Misc_Other</ProductType>
                                   </Miscellaneous>
                           </ProductData>
                   </Product>
           </Message>
           <Message>
                   <MessageID>2</MessageID>
                   <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
                   <Product>
                           <SKU>WAL-0028</SKU>

                           <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_TAX</ProductTaxCode>
                           <Condition>
                                   <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
                           </Condition>
                           <DescriptionData>
                                   <Title><![CDATA[ TOO LOUD TOO BAD 4" SOFT LEATHER Biker WALLET & CHAIN!! ]]></Title>
                                   <Description><![CDATA[ The awesome, 4" Leather Wallet with Chain Black, soft leather, tri-fold four inch wallet. This wallet includes a detachable chain snapping belt loop This great functional and stylish wallet makes a great gift! <BR ]]></Description>



                           </DescriptionData>
                           <ProductData>

                                   <Miscellaneous>
                                           <ProductType>Misc_Other</ProductType>
                                   </Miscellaneous>
                           </ProductData>
                   </Product>
           </Message>
           <Message>
                   <MessageID>3</MessageID>
                   <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
                   <Product>
                           <SKU>WAL-0017</SKU>

                           <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_TAX</ProductTaxCode>
                           <Condition>
                                   <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
                           </Condition>
                           <DescriptionData>
                                   <Title><![CDATA[ PAISLEY Ladies TRIFOLD 7.5 x 4 NEW LEATHER Biker WALLET ]]></Title>
                                   <Description><![CDATA[ The awesome, Ladies Paisley Design Leather Wallet 7.5" x 4" Trifold Wallet ID &amp; Credit Card Slots and Change Pocket. This great functional and stylish wallet makes a great gift! ]]></Description>



                           </DescriptionData>
                           <ProductData>

                                   <Miscellaneous>
                                           <ProductType>Misc_Other</ProductType>
                                   </Miscellaneous>
                           </ProductData>
                   </Product>
           </Message>
           <Message>
                   <MessageID>4</MessageID>
                   <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
                   <Product>
                           <SKU>WAL-0022</SKU>

                           <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_TAX</ProductTaxCode>
                           <Condition>
                                   <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
                           </Condition>
                           <DescriptionData>
                                   <Title><![CDATA[ SKULL & ROSE TATTOO Ladies 7.5 x 4 LEATHER Biker WALLET ]]></Title>
                                   <Description><![CDATA[ The awesome, Ladies Skull and Rose Tattoo Leather Wallet 7.5" x 4" Trifold Wallet ID &amp; Credit Card Slots and Change Pocket. This great functional and stylish wallet makes a great gift! ]]></Description>



                           </DescriptionData>
                           <ProductData>

                                   <Miscellaneous>
                                           <ProductType>Misc_Other</ProductType>
                                   </Miscellaneous>
                           </ProductData>
                   </Product>
           </Message>
```

and this is the error I am getting

```
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>M_HEYGIDDAY_10799467</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>ProcessingReport</MessageType>
<Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <ProcessingReport>
        <DocumentTransactionID>5153491920</DocumentTransactionID>
        <StatusCode>Complete</StatusCode>
        <ProcessingSummary>
            <MessagesProcessed>4</MessagesProcessed>
            <MessagesSuccessful>0</MessagesSuccessful>
            <MessagesWithError>4</MessagesWithError>
            <MessagesWithWarning>0</MessagesWithWarning>
        </ProcessingSummary>
        <StatusCode>Complete</StatusCode>
        <ProcessingSummary>
            <MessagesProcessed>4</MessagesProcessed>
            <MessagesSuccessful>4</MessagesSuccessful>
            <MessagesWithError>0</MessagesWithError>
            <MessagesWithWarning>0</MessagesWithWarning>
        </ProcessingSummary>
        <StatusCode>Complete</StatusCode>
        <ProcessingSummary>
            <MessagesProcessed>4</MessagesProcessed>
            <MessagesSuccessful>4</MessagesSuccessful>
            <MessagesWithError>0</MessagesWithError>
            <MessagesWithWarning>0</MessagesWithWarning>
        </ProcessingSummary>
        <Result>
            <MessageID>1</MessageID>
            <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
            <ResultMessageCode>13043</ResultMessageCode>
            <ResultDescription>0.00 price (standard or sales) will not be accepted. Please ensure that every SKU in your feed has a price at least equal to or greater than 0.01</ResultDescription>
            <AdditionalInfo>
                <SKU>WAL-0011</SKU>
            </AdditionalInfo>
        </Result>
```

and so on for each item...

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I don't see a `price` node in your request.

Comment: i sent a product feed, it shouldnt have price node.

Comment: the problem is that i am getting price error on product feed

Comment: Ok, i fix it with amazon help. 
very good support.
they told me to submit only the price feed and that fix it.


this is what the wrote me.

I checked with your feed and I would suggest you to kindly upload another feed which is the Price feed for all the skus that you have mentioned in the batch id 5153415118. Kindly enter the Price for all the skus and upload it and again reupload the feed that you uploaded for the batch id 5153415118 . I believe there will not be any more issues with it.

Comment: Glad to hear. You can/should add your comment as an answer and then mark it as accepted (as soon as you are allowed). This way others will know that there is a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i fix it with amazon help. very good support. they told me to submit only the price feed and that fix it. this is what the wrote me. I checked with your feed and I would suggest you to kindly upload another feed which is the Price feed for all the skus that you have mentioned in the batch id 5153415118. Kindly enter the Price for all the skus and upload it and again reupload the feed that you uploaded for the batch id 5153415118 . I believe there will not be any more issues with it